# Вывод размера окна в WinApi

Tags: delphi, windows, winapi

Задача состоит в том, что бы вывести в окне координаты верхнего левого угла и размер окна в целом. Функцией GetWindowRect получил координаты для верхнего левого угла, а как теперь размер окна в целом? Нагуглил такую запись:

```
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  GetWindowREct(Form1.Handle,R);
  Label3.Caption := IntToStr(R.Right-R.Left )+':'+IntToStr(R.Bottom-R.Top);
```

Так и не понял что к чему) По другому это сделать как то можно?

Comment: Код на delphi, а в тегах c++? Что-то тут не так.

Answer (score 1):

> Нагуглил такую запись:

Там "Form1.Handle" означает HWND окна, TRect это RECT.
Не забывайте ещё что есть рамка окна, а есть клиентская область.

Answer (score -2):

Если из правой координаты вычесть левую, то получится ширина. <s>Почти получится. Из-за дискретной природы пикселей стоило бы 1 добавить. Если конечно функция не возвращает границу как первый пиксель вне окна, что весьма маловероятно.</s> Похоже, всё-таки возвращает.

С высотой аналогично.

Comment: Всё. Разобрался. Проще чем я думал. Правда не уверен, что запись в отдельных переменных верная. Выводит то он нормально, но наверное всё можно было как то в одну переменную запихнуть. 

  int a=(rect.right)-(rect.left);
  int b=(rect.bottom)-(rect.top);

Comment: Вполне можно обойтись без такого чудовищного количества скобок